# Overriding App (folder) components in next.js 13

Tags: javascript, next.js, next.js13

Let's say I have this folder structure:

[image]

Is there a way of loading the component of the **custom** folder instead of the default one in the **app** folder? If the one does **not exist** in the custom folder, the default one in the app folder should be used.

[image: Folder example]

And this for all the components as long they have the same folder structure?

[image]

I think I will have to override some default functionality

Comment: I don't see a use case where this would be a solution I would choose. You basically want to write your own router which, in Next, is part of the framework. I don't understand why you wouldn't just put the custom one instead of the default one. If this is what you really need, I guess it might be possible to do that with code in the not-found page but the other way around (meaning having fallback catalog for the default ones and using the normal path for the custom ones)

Comment: @grekier maybe this can be useful to understand why I'm asking this: we are creating an application which will be open source. We would like to give other developers the freedom to customize existing pages without having issues when pulling updated from the repository, custom pages will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

After diving into the documentation a bit more I found a possible solution by using **pageExtensions**.

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/pageExtensions

By adding the extension **custom.tsx** to the pageExtensions array, whereby the order is important.

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  pageExtensions: ["custom.tsx", "tsx"],
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

If I now create the About component in the file **page.custom.tsx** with the following content:

```
export default function About() {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>About custom</h1>
    </main>
  );
}
```

This will load the **page.custom.tsx** instead of the **page.tsx** component.

But I get an warning message in the console, which makes sense, something to worry about?:

```
Duplicate page detected. src/app/about/page.custom.tsx and src/app/about/page.tsx resolve to /about
```